# Panel background image works with dynamic but not static address?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, bitmap, panel

This line of code works and retrieves the image from my `bin\Debug\Images\` folder just fine.

```
panel1.BackgroundImage =
    new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "\\Images\\Notavailable.png");
```

This line of code does not retrieve the image from my c: drive's `Images` folder.

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("c:\\Images\\Notavailable.png");
```

Interesting things that might help:

1. The error I receive is "The given path's format is not supported." But, that same exact image loads from the first line I mentioned that is working.
2. I am running as an Administrator.

I really appreciate any help on this problem I can get and thank you all for your time.

Comment: You know that `StartupPath` will point to the Debug folder if you are debugging the application? What happens if you do `if(File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Images\\Notavailable.png")) {}` ?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for replying. This is driving me crazy. To answer your question, the line with Start up path works fine. The image is not found when I use a drive path like "c:\image.PNG"

Comment: Anybody have any ideas about this?

Comment: Does the image need to be in a path descending from the executable?